# Selecting a HTML node based on text containing space

Tags: c#, html, xpath

I'm using Xpath to select an element based on it's text from a web page, which works as long as the text selector doen't contain spaces.

When the selector does contain spaces, however, it fails.
I have looked at: [Locating the node by value containing whitespaces using XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/393840/locating-the-node-by-value-containing-whitespaces-using-xpath)
and [xpath expression to remove whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11776910/xpath-expression-to-remove-whitespace/11777638#11777638)
and [how to get the normalize-space() xpath function to work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829176/how-to-get-the-normalize-space-xpath-function-to-work?rq=1)
but that did not work.

A sample of the html that fails:

```
<tr style="vertical-align:top;">
        <td style="height:15px;"></td>
        <td class="cs9D60B82">Yellow&nbsp;Fees</td>
        <td class="cs9D60B82">Group1</td>
        <td class="cs9D60B82">Yes</td>
        <td class="cs9DB0B82"></td>
        <td class="cs9D60B82">QD&nbsp;1,234.56</td>
</tr>
```

These work, but could return other nodes starting the same text too:

```
"//td[starts-with( normalize-space(), 'Yellow')]"  
"//td[starts-with(text(), 'Yellow')]"
```

These don't work:

```
 "//td[normalize-space(.) = 'Yellow Fees']"  
 "//td[translate(text(), '&#9;&#xA;&#xD;','') = 'YellowFees']"
 "//td[translate(text(), ' &#9;&#xA;&#xD;','') = 'Yellow&#xA0;Fees']"  
 "//td[translate(text(), '&nbsp;','') = 'YellowFees']"  
 "//td[translate(text(), '&#9;&#xA;&#xD;','') = 'Yellow&nbsp;Fees']"
 "//td[matches( text(), 'Yellow&nbsp;Fees')]"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/selenium-users/IJP6VKnnEeQ

```
"//td[starts-with( normalize-space(), 'Yellow\u00A0Fees')]"
```

works!

Comment: I was not able to get similar results using http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath. I even registered the entity `<!DOCTYPE html [`
`    <!ENTITY nbsp "&#160;"> `
`]>`

Comment: @JoelM.Lamsen Did you try something similar to  `//td[contains(text(),'Yellow Fees')]`

Comment: @callisto: Ah, the problem is &nbsp does not translate into a white-space, it translates into a non-breakable whitespace - of course, stupid.

Comment: try this link (http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/55a7049548fec24a1a6c2bc43c79c566)