# click Menu item with same ID using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium

Below is my HTML snippet and code I tried. I need to Click the **Integrated Consoles** menu item. I tried like below, But nothing happens and no error as well. Kindly help me to select the Specific Menu Item using the text inside the tag.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//td[contains text(),'Integrated Consoles']").click()
```

HTMl sample Snippet

```
<td nowrap="" id="MENU_TD110">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Integrated Consoles&nbsp;</td>
<td nowrap="" id="MENU_TD110">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;System Information&nbsp;</td>
<td nowrap="" id="MENU_TD110">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;More Tools&nbsp;</td>
```

Comment: can you change it to `.//td[contains(text(),'Integrated Consoles')]` and try

Comment: @NarendraRajput Worked. Thanks!

Comment: You should use normalize-space which trims leading and trailing spaces as well as reduce in between spaces to a single space. normalize-space(text(),'Integrated Consoles'). This way your xpath will get exact text instead of text like 'Newer Integrated Consoles etc'. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11776910/xpath-expression-to-remove-whitespace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parentheses `()` are missing inside your `contains` method just enclose like below and try -

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//td[contains(text(),'Integrated Consoles')]").click()
```