# C++: Reading XML files using with 'preserveWhitespace' enabled

Tags: c++, com, msxml

I'm using `IXMLDOMNode::get_childNodes()` with `preserveWhiteSpace` set to true, which causes it to treat carriage returns between elements as nodes. In my child list, I get a few nodes with the name `#text`.

Is there any way to remove these nodes from my list? I have a `CComPtr<IXMLDOMNodeList>` object, and there are no members that allow me to add/remove to it.

I'm thinking of using `selectNodes()` instead, and passing an expression that ignores all nodes with the name `#text`. Would this be possible?

I just tried `selectNodes()` and passed the expression `//*[not(self::#text)]`, but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: [`IXMLDOMNodeList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms757028(v=vs.85).aspx) doesn't look like it wants to be modified as you've found.  Depending on what needs to consume that list and/or what further processing you need to do, removing white space (but not other text nodes, right?) on the front-end sounds reasonable.  This may be of some help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11776910/xpath-expression-to-remove-whitespace

Comment: If you don't want the whitespace nodes, why are you setting `preserveWhiteSpace` to true in the first place?

Comment: The XML files are an outline for a report. It has a grid, with rows/columns. I want to add some whitespace before some of the row names so I can add a header. I can add something like [space%4%] and match it to draw 4 whitespaces whenever it appears, but I would prefer not to if it can be avoided.

Comment: @jebusayah So does that mean there's some formatting "baked in" to the XML data, via strategically-placed spacing?  (*Going on that assumption*...) ...while it's going to add work, you might look at [XSLT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT) for your formatting needs.  XML is a vehicle for the data, but isn't traditionally used as its presentation.