# can we trim() an xpath result?

Tags: xpath

Hi friends I am not very familiar with XPATH, and have a small question:

If I have a node that looks like this:

```
<books>
  <book>   book name.  </book>
</books>
```

and I ask for this expression:

```
//books/book
```

then, is there a way for the xpath to return the normalize-string()'d version of the book name?
as in, replace "   book name.  " and return only "book name." without any trailing or leading spaces?
is that even possible with xpath.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [xpath expression to remove whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11776910/xpath-expression-to-remove-whitespace)

Comment: Hi, no, unfortunately, I ended up just using Trim() in golang, which sucks because I wanted an xpath only solution... oh well...

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't this work?

```
normalize-space(/books/book/text())
```

Comment: If it's XPath 2.0+, you could just do `/books/book/normalize-space()`

Comment: While `normalize-space()` is obviously the extremely common solution to this problem, please note it does more than just trim leading and trailing space.  It also reduces internal sequences of whitespace characters.